# Formula for partial fractions with repeated roots

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, summation, partial-fractions

I've been trying to find a formula for the partial fraction of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials, $\operatorname{deg}(P(x))<\operatorname{deg}(Q(x))$ and $Q(x)$ has repeated roots.
I was able to proof that if $G(x)$ doesn't have repeated repeated roots then $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{P(\alpha_k)}{Q^\prime(\alpha_k)(x-\alpha_k)}$ where $\alpha_k$ is the $k$'th root of $Q(x)$. However I wasn't able to adapt this to make it work for when $Q(x)$ has repeated roots.
I tried splitting the $Q(x)$ into 2 polynomials, one with the roots used just once and the other with whatever is left over then applying the formula above to the polynomial with distinct roots and working from there however I didn't manage to get very far.

Comment: When you write $G(x)$ do you mean $Q(x)$?

Comment: Write $Q(x) = q(x)(x-r)^m$ and see what you get. I think it will be a sum of $m$ terms involving $(x-r)^k, k=1..m$.

Comment: @Joe Yes, sorry. I've edited now.

Comment: The simplest case is $Q(x)=(x-a)^n$. You end up with $P(x) = A_1(x-a)^{n-1}+\cdots + A_{n-1}(x-a) + A_n$, where $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \sum \frac{A_j}{(x-a)^j}$ is the partial fraction decomposition. This requires you to write $P(x)$ in "base $x-a$".